# Is it possible to run a program in C language without libraries?

Tags: libraries, functions

I was working on a C program and i just noted that i can execute my program even if i didn't declared the required libraries, this is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

  char x[999],y[999]="copyme";
  strcpy(x,y);
  printf("Output: %s",x); 

  return 0;
}
```

After i undeclared the `string.h` libray, the program can always be executed and produce the result. As i know, any function used needs a libray that specify it's job, logically, since there is no `string.h` the `strcpy` function mustn't work, thus, there must be no output.

I supposed that the other library (`stdio.h`) is acting as a vice, but after i undeclared it aswell, the program can be executed and produce the output even if there is no library declared. how that can happen?, Do libraries have no role?.

Comment: After you undeclare the libraries, are you recompiling the source?

Comment: Check out [this article](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) for some low-level details of programming in C and removing a lot of standard stuff that comes along for the ride when you compile and link your program.

Comment: There is a good explanation on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336814/why-include-stdio-h-is-not-required-to-use-printf . Standard libs are often included and linked in by default, e.g. gcc .

Comment: @adeady Ofcourse i did.

Comment: Those `#include` directives are not declarations. The `#include`d standard library header is supposed to provide declarations for the standard library functions, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, "libraries" and "headers" are different things. A header file may be declarations for all things in a library, some things in a library or simply declarations for some/all things in another compilation unit.

Second, C will blithely assume that an undeclared function takes only integer parameters and returns an integer. This is pretty much enough for `strcpy` (the default naked int may be enough for a pointer, and pointer-to-int coersion is, I think, implementation-defined) and if it works for strcpy it'll work for what you do with `printf`.

Typically, both `strcpy` and `printf` live in the standard C library, which will (normally) automatically be included in the linking phase, where the presence of the unlinked symbols will cause the relevant linkage to happen.

Comment: Also worth pointing out is that any compiler adhering to C99 or later will balk at undeclared functions, and most will at least emit a warning if warnings are turned on.

Comment: @Blrfl Hm, yes, that may be a sign that I learned C in the late 80s...

Comment: For what it's worth, so did I (1987).  One of my mentors went to great lengths to make sure I understood that the warnings had better be turned on and if the compiler emits any, the code's not finished.  :-)

Comment: BTW, the standard permits that the compiler, when you use `printf` while including `<stdio.h>` (or `strcpy` wih `<string.h>`), compile a `printf` call (or `strcpy`) to or using some magic (e.g. compiler builtins), and actually [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is (often) doing such an optimization (for both `printf` & `strcpy`)